# Should one use GET/POST or specific methods for class based views in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm just wondering what you think the best practice is for class based views in Django.

On one hand, you have something like this which uses GET and POST.

```
class User_Logout(View):

    def get(self, request):
        auth.logout(request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('frontend-login'))
```

This would map to a urls.py containing:

```
from frontend.views import User_Logout

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'logout$', User_Logout.as_view(), name="frontend-logout"),
    )
```

Or, something that uses specific methods. For example, I could create a class called Score_Dashboard(View), encapsulating every page associated with scores as methods of that class.

Something along the lines of...

```
class Scores(View):

    def score_one(self, request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.youtube.com')


    def score_two(self, request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.youtube.com')
```

And then call each of these as a method of an instance of each class inside urls.py:

```
from views import Scores

scores = Scores()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'score_one$', scores.score_two, name="score_one"),
    url(r'score_two$', scores.score_two, name="score_one"),
    )
```

So my question is, which one is more 'proper' or even perhaps 'better' and why?

Another way to asking this is, should every page have its own class?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is a bit mixed up, apparently the last example would not be the way, if you need a view to alter its behavior based on difference requests, create a view that does that, pass the altering parameter in the url as a param and put the logic in the View.

Comment: Hi, sorry - I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'difference requests'? By create a view, do you mean create a new class? So by that, should every page have its own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you don't need to use a Class Based view, don't use it.**

The most simple definition of a view is with a function. Your views should already be organized per app so you don't need to create another subgroup (or if you *really* want to organize views inside an app, just create two different views file):

```
def score_one(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.youtube.com')


def score_two(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.youtube.com')
```

CBV should be reversed for case where you are extending built-in classes provide by Django, to make list of objects, change form, etc.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying only use CBV's when you need more than one functionality from each page, for example a GET and POST. However, if one is just fetching a page, don't bother with the extra subgroup?

Comment: For me, a CBV should be used only when you are doing something quite generic with a model. [Examples on this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) will give you an idea of what I meant. If you are not just listing, displaying or altering instance(s) of a Model, using CBV can take much more lines of code and then a simple function is way more readable.

Comment: @MaximeLorant Why? the TemplateView is as simple as anything else and does not require any kind of imports, if you need to pass data to the context your can always override the get_context_data method.

Comment: I see your point. Um, so I guess another question I had was for the urls.py. Is there anyway to skip over the 'scores = Scores()' line? Or must I instantiate a new object for every class?

I know that when I use classes involving GET and POST, I can just use Scores.as_view().

Comment: @petkostas It is quite the exception indeed :) You can use `TemplateView` directly in `urls.py`, it is quite useful if you don't want to configure the flatpages module just for one page... But if you want to get one object, I think a function of two lines, with the `render` shortcut is easier to read IMO.
@suitegamer Why don't you want to use just a function? I recommend you: http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes :-)

Comment: @Maxime Lorant I'm really just trying to learn Django - so I'm just asking all of the appropriate questions :).

Comment: @suitegamer Indeed. Don't worry this kind of questions are good to ask :) It will work with CBV, but it is not the common practice. Once you will have [dig a little on Github](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/blog/views.py) or in the doc, you will see CBV are used only few times if the class takes less code/characters than a function.

Comment: @Maxime Lorant - That's great, thanks for your help. I learned a while ago that even though I think my question is stupid, it's probably best to ask it anyways haha. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question, it would be easier to catch different args in your URLs and process them in one view :

```
def scores(request, score):
    if score == "score_one":
        # do something

    if score == "score_two":
        # do something else

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'(?P<score>score_one|score_two)$', scores, name="scores"),
)
```

Using Class Based Views in this situation is maybe not needed (especially if you're just redirecting).